# R shiny: Change "height" attribute of rectangle in gvisTimeline

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, svg, shiny

I use `gvisTimeline` in a R `Shiny`-App:

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

ui <-fluidRow(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js", {{ suppressDependencies("d3") }})
  ),
  htmlOutput("timeline")
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

dat <- data.frame(Term=c("1","2","3"),
                  President=c("Whashington", "Adams", "Jefferson"),
                  start=as.Date(x=c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", "1801-02-03")),
                  end=as.Date(x=c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", "1809-02-03")))

output$timeline <-renderGvis({
                    gvisTimeline(data=dat[,-1], rowlabel="President",
                    start="start", end="end")
          })
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to change the height of the middle rectangle. I achieve this by selecting the appropriate `svg` element in JavaScript Console:

```
d3.select('svg:nth-child(1) g:nth-child(5) rect:nth-child(2)')
.attr('height', 42)
.attr('y', 40);
```

How can I intergrate this code into the Shiny-App in order to get this one rectangle in desired height and y-coordinate from the beginning? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the timeline is transferred from the Google Server a few milliseconds after the page is loaded. You need to execute your JavaScript code after this transfer happened, i.e. 50 or 500 ms after the page is initialized. The following code will execute it every 50 ms, which works but is far from perfect.

1. In UI, you need a dummy output "uiOutput("timelineAdjustment")":

   ```
   uiOutput("timelineAdjustment")
   ```
2. In Server, you need to define it as follows:

   ```
   autoInvalidate50msec <- reactiveTimer(50, session)
   output$timelineAdjustment <- renderUI({
      autoInvalidate50msec()
      HTML("<script type='text/javascript'>d3.select('#timeline svg:nth-child(1) g:nth-child(5) rect:nth-child(2)').attr('height', 42).attr('y', 40);</script>")
   })
   ```

Alternatively, the equivalent definition if you just execute it once (1000ms) after the page is loaded:

```
output$timelineAdjustment <- renderUI({
    HTML("<script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout(function() { d3.select('#timeline svg:nth-child(1) g:nth-child(5) rect:nth-child(11)').attr('height', 41).attr('y', 41); },1000);</script>")
})
```

If there is a better way of achieving this, I'd be glad to hear!